# Algorithms for constructing categories with minimal distance

Tags: cluster-analysis, categories

I am looking for an algorithm (or more algorithms) that would allow me to construct N categories for M items with minimal distance. Categories have X attributes that can be adjusted and based on these attributes a distance between category and an item can be calculated.

One obvious way are some clustering methods and then deriving categories from centers of clusters. However, I would like to explore some algorithms that operate purely on modifying the categories, i.e. propose list of categories, calculate distances to each item, modify the categories. Distances for each of the X attributes could be independently calculated.

Comment: Sounds like PAM to me.

Comment: Thanks, I will educate myself!